# Calculating percentile for each request from a log file based on start time and end time using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, percentile

I have a `simulation.log` file where it will have below results and I want to calculate 5th, 25th, 95th, 99th percentile of each request using shell script by reading the file.

Below is a sample `simulation.log` file where 1649410339141 and 1649410341026 are start and end time in milliseconds.

```
REQUEST1    somelogprinted  TTP123099SM000202 002   1649410339141   1649410341026   OK  
REQUEST2    somelogprinted  TTP123099SM000202 001   1649410339141   1649410341029   OK
......
```

I tried below code but did not give me any result and I am not a Unix developer:

```sh
FILE=filepath 

sort -n $* > $FILE 

N=$(wc -l $FILE | awk '{print $1}') 

P50=$(dc -e "$N 2 / p") 
P90=$(dc -e "$N 9 * 10 / p") 

P99=$(dc -e "$N 99 * 100 / p") echo ";; 
50th, 90th and 99th percentiles for 
$N data points" awk "FNR==$P50 || FNR==$P90 || FNR==$P99" $FILE
```

Sample output:

```
Request | 5thpercentile | 25Percentile  | 95Percentile | 99Percentile

Request1 |  657  |          786  |     821    |          981

Request2 |  453  |          654  |     795    |         854
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It's not clear what `$*` is here or which numbers should be captured, but in general, if you are using Awk anyway, probably take care of everything in one Awk script. Can you explain what the expected output should be for the sample you provided, and why?